# Executing .reg file [c#]

Tags: c#, file, import, registry

I'm trying to execute a .reg file from c# program.
I understood that the following code should work:

```
 string filepath = "C:\\Users\\...\\test.reg";
 Process regeditProcess = Process.Start("regedit.exe" , filepath);
 regeditProcess.WaitForExit();
```

but it doesn't!
I see a message of a successful keys creation in regitsry, but I don't see it was really added.

thanks for any help.

Comment: Depending on where you want to add stuff to the registry, you (that is, the application) might require administrative rights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If regedit tells you that the values were added, but you cannot see them, then most likely the [registry redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx) is confusing you. In other words, you are hoping to import into the 64 bit view, but import into the 32 bit view, or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks! but when I run test.reg separately it is adding the values... what should I do?

Comment: Start off by looking in the other registry view from that where you expect the values to be added. I presume the values are under `HKLM\Software`?

Comment: I found it! under HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node.. I am now looking for a way to make it added in the right place

Comment: Run the regedit from sysnative? Or avoid regedit altogether and write the registry values using code rather than .reg.

Comment: Or use a 64 bit process rather than 32.

Comment: running from sysnative doesn't work, so i'll try the other options. thanks a lot!